# remoteEntry.mjs file from ModuleFederation is failing to load on IIS

Tags: angular, iis, micro-frontend, nx-workspace, angular-module-federation

I developed a basic demo micro frontend project using nx,module federation with angular. When I am trying to host it on my IIS, the remote apps are working fine, but the host(or) shell application is failing to load. The remoteEntry.mjs file from either remote apps is not being loaded. When tried to access 'http://localhost/app1/remoteEntry.js' I am getting a HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found.

I have no idea about how to change the handlers thing mentioned in the 'Things you can try'. I am a beginner in this.[image: Result when I try to access http://localhost/app1/remoteEntry.mjs]

Comment: The error log doesn't show the key factor that lead to this 404.3 error, please enable failed request tracing, it will provide the key error and warning. This link provide the method to enable failed request tracing to capture the detailed error: [failed request tracing](https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).